# Sitecore AKS Solutions Deployment

Tags: aks

I Installed sitecore 10.2 in my AKS Cluster as per official sitecore image.(https://github.com/Sitecore/container-deployment/releases/tag/sxp%2F10.2.0.006766.683). The CM and CD all pods are running. With successfully setup.

I deployed with my solution,( using through docker solution image, cm and CD image). I replaced the official sitecore cm image to my solution cm image, The pod was on 0/1 stage. I got 403 health/start issue

Can you please help me, How to troubleshoot this issue???

Thanks,
Biswajit

---

Yes, I am using custom images for CM, CD and Solution. But its failed for CM and CD pod up.

Please check the logs for refences.

```
Nested Exception

Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: The network path was not found




ManagedPoolThread #1 04:29:41 ERROR Exception processing remote events from database: web02
Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand..ctor(IDbCommand command, DataProviderTransaction transaction, Boolean openConnection)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.c__DisplayClass26_0.b__0()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.c__DisplayClass29_0.b__0()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateReader(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.d__27`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventQueue.ProcessEvents(Action`2 handler)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseQueuedEvents()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: The network path was not found


ManagedPoolThread #9 04:29:41 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #9 04:29:41 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJob.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`2 body)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.PerformUpdate(IEnumerable`1 indexableInfo, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand..ctor(IDbCommand command, DataProviderTransaction transaction, Boolean openConnection)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.c__DisplayClass26_0.b__0()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.c__DisplayClass29_0.b__0()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateReader(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerLinkDataProvider.GetLinks(String sql, Item item, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.d__171.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.UpdateClones(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem versionIndexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.UpdateItemVersion(IProviderUpdateContext context, Item version, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoUpdate(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.Update(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.c__DisplayClass114_2.b__0(IndexableInfo info, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object )

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: The network path was not found




ManagedPoolThread #10 04:29:43 ERROR Exception processing remote events from database: web02
Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand..ctor(IDbCommand command, DataProviderTransaction transaction, Boolean openConnection)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.c__DisplayClass26_0.b__0()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.c__DisplayClass29_0.b__0()
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateReader(String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.d__27`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventQueue.ProcessEvents(Action`2 handler)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseQueuedEvents()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: The network path was not found


ManagedPoolThread #3 04:29:45 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 04:29:45 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
19304 04:29:47 ERROR ParTech.Modules.UrlRewriter: Cannot load rules folder with ID '' from Sitecore. Verify that it exists.
18960 04:29:47 ERROR Health check reporting storage manager http completed after 0.1496ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error message: 'Unknown connection string. Name: 'reporting.apikey'''
```

Comment: So CM pod runs fine if sitecore image, but gives 403 if you use custom image? are you able to get any logs from CM? Have you changed entry point in any way? If you try running the custom image in docker desktop does it work fine? Suggest double checking all your credentials are being passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have provided is stating that the CM instance is unable to access the network location for the SQL server.

In order to diagnose this issue, you need first look at what connectionstrings are in the config file, then see if they are being correctly overridden via environment variable.

**Access the config file as below.**

List pods and copy name:

```
kubectl get pods -n sitecore
```

Exec into pod:

```
kubectl exec -it your-pod-name -n sitecore -- cmd
```

Navigate to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app_config

Enter following:

```
more connectionstrings.config
```

Leave the output from the above open in one window, then open another window to find the environment variables for the pod.

**View Environment variables**

Open new window, connect and then enter:

```
kubectl describe pod your-pod-name -n sitecore
```

**Compare**

You should see a corresponding environment variable to overwrite each connection string. For example Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Core, to overwrite the core connection string.

If one is missing, then what could be happening is that you are trying to access an untransformed SQL location (i.e. what ever was originally in the config file). Obviously this is not accessible from within kubernetes.

**Next things to check**

If you are connecting to an external datasource, then check nothing is blocking access i.e. firewall ports etc. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/basic-troubleshooting-outbound-connections

If you are connecting to an interal kubernetes pod, then make sure that the servername *(by default this is configured in secret file sitecore-databaseservername.txt)* you are using in the connectionstring matches the name of the service that is in front of the sql pod. By default this should be **mssql**.